# Python module reusing the same object

Tags: python, global

This module returns a list. When I call the module with `ipscan.scan('192.168.11', 161)` the list gets appended instead of returning a new one. The only way I managed to "reset" the list was by reassign the global parameter key "node_list"  like this `ipscan.scan.func_globals['node_list'] = []`

Being a beginner I don't know how to describe the problem better. 
Thank you!

```
import socket
from threading import Thread

socket.setdefaulttimeout(1)

node_list = []


def probe(ip, port):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    try:
        s.connect((ip, port))
        node_list.append(ip)
    except:
        pass

    s.close()


def scan(ipnet, port):
    for x in range(1,255):
        ip = '{0}.{1}'.format(ipnet, x)

        t = Thread(target=probe, args=(ip, port))
        t.start()

    return node_list
```

The correct initialization of `node_list`:

```
import socket
from threading import Thread

socket.setdefaulttimeout(1)


def probe(ip, port):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    try:
        s.connect((ip, port))
        node_list.append(ip)
    except:
        pass

    s.close()


def scan(ipnet, port):
    global node_list
    node_list = []

    for x in range(1,255):
        ip = '{0}.{1}'.format(ipnet, x)

        t = Thread(target=probe, args=(ip, port))
        t.start()

    return node_list
```

Comment: Have you tried just call node_list = [] before the scan loop?

Comment: Yes, the same behavior.

Comment: When you say " the list gets appended instead of returning a new one." you mean that if you call "scan" twice it appends the new values in the same list?

Comment: Yes, appends the new values to the same list

Comment: well, so in this case initialize in the beginning of the scan function, should work.
Other alternative is to use a Thread class.
Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I tried that also. Is not working. Scan function just dispatches the threads. Maybe it's not a good idea to return the `node_list` in the `scan` function. I tried also adding a `main` function in which I initiate the node_list and call `scan`, then return the list. Not working either.

Comment: Ok, I initiated node_list inside the scan function but I declared it `global`. Was that easy.

Comment: Good you found it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple enough, don't declare your list outside of the function.

Move `node_list = []` into your function definition:

```
def scan(ipnet, port):
    node_list = []
    for x in range(1,255):
        ip = '{0}.{1}'.format(ipnet, x)

        t = Thread(target=probe, args=(ip, port))
        t.start()

    return node_list
```

Essentially, you want to read up a little bit more on namespaces.

Comment: In the OP's code, the `probe` function is appending to `node_list`.

Comment: With the mention that `node_list` should be `global`.